# Not able to pass self (which implements a protocol) to init method of a class instantiation.(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift-protocols

I have a protocol like so

```
public protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedType someType

    func doFoo(fooObject:someType) -> Void
}
```

I have a class that implements this protocol

```
public class Foo<T> : FooProtocol {
    private let _doFoo : (T) -> Void

    init<P : FooProtocol where P.someType == T>(_dep : P) {
        _doFoo = _dep.doFoo
    }

    public func doFoo(fooObject: T) {
        _doFoo(fooObject)
    }
}
```

Everything upto here looks good to me, Now in another class I implement the FooProtocol with `someType = MyType`, then when I try to initialize the `Foo` class with `T = MyType` by passing `self` in the init method of the `Foo` class I get a compilation error, what am I doing wrong here?

Error message:

> " Cannot invoke init with an argument list of type `(_dep: NSObject -> () -> MyView)`"

```
public class MyView : UIViewController, FooProtocol {

    func doFoo(fooObject : MyType) {
        ...
    }

    // Here I want to initialize the Foo<T> class
    let fooInstant : Foo<MyType> = Foo.init(_dep : self)
    // I get the error message on the above line the error
    // message reads "Cannot invoke init with an argument list
    // of type `(_dep: NSObject -> () -> MyView)`
}
```

Isn't self conforming to FooProtocol with `someType == MyType`, and since I am trying to init a `Foo` object with `T == MyType` this should technically work yes?

Comment: Can you specify actually what goal you want to achieve with this approach & why ?

Comment: ok I have a class that has methods that perform asynchronous tasks, I need to write a generic callback interface (protocol) which I can then implement in classes which use these asynchronous functions and pass the generic protocol into these functions as parameters, from which I can then do a callback on successful completion of the asynchronous method

Comment: Ok, For this you don't need any init method i guess. you can add delegate to the protocol in the `viewController` and will be able to callback through that delegate the protocol methods. like : `let delegate: FooProtocol?` and with delegate just call the protocol methods like: `delegate?.dooFoo()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually doesn't appear to be anything to do with your generics or protocol conformance. It's simply that you're trying to access `self` in your property assignment before `self` has been initialised (default property values are assigned *during* initialisation).

The solution therefore is to use a lazy property like so:

```
lazy var fooInstant : Foo<MyType> = Foo(_dep : self)
```

This will now be created when it's first accessed, and therefore after `self` has been initialised.

Comment: Yep this works! I understand now, in order to get the self you need to access it from inside the instance scope, and I have been trying to access the self from a static scope, I hate this stupid language

Comment: Even with the edit, `self` would be initialized at this point when the class is loaded. The reason why it didn't originally work was because of the type mismatch and has got nothing to do with initialization. It is very important to understand this.

Comment: @avismara I'm not sure what you mean... `self` is not initialised until one of its initialisers has been called – and you cannot access any instance members on `self` until that has happened, therefore you cannot treat it as an instance.

Comment: It is true if you are referring to `self` as an instance of `MyClass`. Agreed. But the meaning of `self` is entirely different when you use it outside of the methods/functions/closures. It refers to `MyClass` itself. THAT would be initialized at that time when `MyClass` is loaded onto the memory.

Comment: @avismara Ah okay, thanks for clarifying! I have edited my answer.

Comment: Ah, better. Now it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

It is very much important to understand the context of `self` in the place where it is used. In that context, `self` doesn't mean an instance of `MyView`.

You can, however get it to work by doing this:

```
let fooInstant : Foo<String> = Foo.init(_dep : MyView())
```

I cannot say more without understanding what you want to do here.

Comment: yes what you mentioned works, but thats a different instance and not the instance I want

Comment: All though the reason that @originaluser2 has given is wrong as to why this implementation fails, go with the their solution. I think that's what you want.

Comment: @avismara Wrong, how?

Comment: @avismara Yes I am trying out his solution right now

Comment: `self` in the context is actually something else. Here `self` is actually the `Class` MyView itself not an instance of it. `self` will be an implicit argument in cases where you are using it inside a method/closures, in which case it would be true.

Answer (score 0):

So seems like this works

```
public class MyView : UIViewController, FooProtocol {

    var fooInstant : Foo<MyType>!

    public func initializeFooInstant(){
        fooInstant  = Foo.init(_dep : self)
    }


    func doFoo(fooObject : MyType) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I think system does not let you access self to initialise let properties because there is no guarantee that self is fully initialised when your let property is being initialised.

In the above case you will just have to make sure that fooInstance is initialised before accessing it else the program will crash.

Hope this helps.