# '(NSObject) -> () -> ViewController()' does not conform to expected type 'classDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, audiokit

I am new at OO/mobile programming and I am working on making an app that make sound analysis (trying to reach a tuner app soon).

I'm get a little confused with OO sometimes, can't deny it.
As the subtitle says, I'm get that error and don't know why. Lets see the code ViewController():

```
    import UIKit
    import AudioKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, SoundAnalyserDelegate{

        let soundAnalyser = SoundAnalyser(delegate: self) //getting error here



        @IBOutlet var frequencyLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var amplitudeLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet var note: UILabel!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            soundAnalyser.start()
```

This part of the code initiates the class SoundAnalyser and delegates itself.

Look at SoundAnalyser code:

```
    class SoundAnalyser {

        var delegate:SoundAnalyserDelegate?

        let minimum = Double(160)
        let maximum = Double(1400)

        var mic: AKMicrophone
        var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker
        fileprivate var silence: AKBooster
        fileprivate var timer: Timer?
        fileprivate var notesArray: [(String, Double)]?

        init(delegate: SoundAnalyserDelegate){
            mic = AKMicrophone()
            tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(mic, hopSize: minimum, peakCount: maximum)
            silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain:0)
            notesArray = self.getNotesFrequencies()
            self.delegate = delegate

        }


        func start(){
            AudioKit.output = silence
```

At SoundAnalyser(), I try to call a function from ViewController here:

```
        func tick(){
            let amp = tracker.amplitude
            let freq = tracker.frequency


            if amp > 0.05 && freq > minimum && freq < maximum{
                let readNote = notesArray![analyseCapturedSound()]

                delegate?.setLabelAmp(String(format:"%f", amp)) //Setting the text of a label from the UI

                delegate?.setLabelFreq(String(format:"%f", freq))

    //            delegate?.setLabelNote(String(format:"%f", readNote))

                print("freq:", freq," amp:", amp," NOTE: \(readNote)")
            }
        }
```

Is this very wrong as OO point of view? Or I'm forgetting something?

I mean.. calling a func from the 'father' class... don't seems the best OO way but it's the only I'm seeing to do it.

If needed, you can check the project here:

https://github.com/denisb411/Microphone_Analyser_AK

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call the delegate in `soundAnalyser.delegate = self`

Comment: You can use a `lazy` property – see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/36996573/2976878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialized your object with `lazy var`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SoundAnalyserDelegate{

    lazy var fontSize : SoundAnalyser = {
        return SoundAnalyser(delegate: self) 
    }()

    @IBOutlet var frequencyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var amplitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var note: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        soundAnalyser.start()

    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why and how you reached this conclusion?

Comment: I have done some minor changes to make the code compilable but I would probably prefer using an IUO or a lazy property.

Comment: @DenisCandido When I try a minimal example in a playground I get an error that `self` is not defined on the same line you get your error. Don't know why the error is different but you can't use `self` before the `init` has run. The answer fixes this by moving the initialisation to the first time it is used

Comment: @Sulthan Edited answer with lazy property.

Comment: @DenisCandido JeremyP is correct thanx for the explanation also check the edited answer.

Comment: I need to search about this var property. Still very unfamilliar with this language... Please can you make a fast explain of the lazy property?

Comment: @JeremyP That would be because OP's class inherits from `NSObject`, so Swift is (quite cleverly) resolving `self` to `NSObjectProtocol`'s `self()` instance method (and because instance methods are curried functions – that's `(NSObject) -> () -> ViewController `.

Comment: @DenisCandido err which version of Swift are you using? Swift 2 and 3 do have an equivalent to try catch

Comment: @Hamish Thanks, I thought it might be something like that.

Comment: @DenisCandido Check this tutorial for that https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-are-lazy-variables

Comment: @NiravD You can totally say `lazy var soundAnalyser: SoundAnalyser = SoundAnalyser(delegate: self)`

Comment: Thanks a lot @NiravD. It's working now. But can you please tell me if this is a good citizen patten or not? There's a better way to do it? (for good lecture reasons). I am trying to follow the best good citizen ways as possible.